# Python multiprocessing Pool.map not faster than calling the function once

Tags: python

I have a very large list of strings (originally from a text file) that I need to process using python. Eventually I am trying to go for a map-reduce style of parallel processing.

I have written a "mapper" function and fed it to `multiprocessing.Pool.map()`, but it takes the same amount of time as simply calling the mapper function with the full set of data. I must be doing something wrong.

I have tried multiple approaches, all with similar results.

```
def initial_map(lines):
    results = []
    for line in lines:
        processed = # process line (O^(1) operation)
        results.append(processed)
    return results

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = list(open("../../log.txt", 'r'))
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    partitions = chunks(lines, len(lines)/8)
    results = pool.map(initial_map, partitions, 1)
```

So the chunks function makes a list of sublists of the original set of lines to give to the `pool.map()`, then it should hand these 8 sublists to 8 different processes and run them through the mapper function. When I run this I can see all 8 of my cores peak at 100%. Yet it takes 22-24 seconds.

When I simple run this (single process/thread):

```
lines = list(open("../../log.txt", 'r'))
results = initial_map(results)
```

It takes about the same amount of time. ~24 seconds. I only see one process getting to 100% CPU.

I have also tried letting the pool split up the lines itself and have the mapper function only handle one line at a time, with similar results.

```
def initial_map(line):
    processed = # process line (O^(1) operation)
    return processed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = list(open("../../log.txt", 'r'))
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(initial_map, lines)
```

~22 seconds.

Why is this happening? Parallelizing this should result in faster results, shouldn't it?

Comment: How large is the data you are passing around? My guess is that your CPU is saturated mostly by serialising and deserealising data.

Comment: Your processing is rather I/O bound, so it is not CPU limited as it mostly waits for some data to come. With mulitple processes you sometime add overhead, which even slows things down.

Comment: Just a heads up, [the third argument to `pool.map` is chunksize](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) removing the need to write your own `chunks` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the amount of work done in one iteration is very small, you're spending a big proportion of the time just communicating with your subprocesses, which is expensive. Instead, try to pass bigger slices of your data to the processing function. Something like the following:

```
slices = (data[i:i+100] for i in range(0, len(data), 100)

def process_slice(data):
    return [initial_data(x) for x in data]

pool.map(process_slice, slices)

# and then itertools.chain the output to flatten it
```

(don't have my comp. so can't give you a full working solution nor verify what I said)

**Edit:** or see the 3rd comment on your question by @ubomb.

Comment: I believe that is what my approach in the first block of code is doing. chunks gets a list of "slices" to give to map and the actual mapper function loops through them.

Comment: well then increase the chunk size — that's all I'm saying. by what I can tell from the code snippets you posted, you're processing a single line at a time.